# Compositional Layout UICollectionView iOS 14.4 can't scroll to the last item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have problem with Compositional Layout in UICollectionView only on iOS 14.4 or earlier, on iOS 14.5 is fine.

This is my code

```
let heightDimension = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(140)
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                    heightDimension: heightDimension))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .absolute(232),
                                                                 heightDimension: heightDimension),
                                               subitems: [item])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.interGroupSpacing = 8
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
```

This is how it look on iOS 14.4 I can't scroll to the last element.

[image]
This is how it look on iOS 14.5 - everything works fine.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Why do you not simply change the minimum iOS version for your app to iOS 14.5?